# Counting while lisiting in a single SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, mariadb, backend

The title is pathetic, I don't really know how to word the issue better than this, let me explain.

I've got a `Tests` table and `TestAttendance` table where I create a record each time user takes a test with user id and test id.

**What I want to do is: While listing the tests I want to show total number of attendants for each test.**

```
(
  SELECT COUNT(ta.id)
  FROM TestUserAttendances ta
  JOIN Tests t ON ta.testId = t.id
)
```

The above query returning the total number of attendants without distinguishing test, so the total number of attendants added to each test while I want it to display each test individually.

Comment: The quality of the title is commensurate with the quality of the question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT ta.test_id,count(*) from FROM TestUserAttendances ta JOIN Tests t ON 
ta.testId = t.id group by ta.test_id
```

Comment: Spamming the `accept as answer` button right now. Thanks, I did know about `group by` never thought about it.